# change JSON in 2D format react native

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, reactjs, react-native

I have JSON as response from API like this:-

```
JSON=[
{
    product:{"final_price": 500,"customers_basket_quantity": 3,"products_id": 123, "products_name": 'cotton'},
    attribute:{
        Color:{color:'red',123,color_id:123},
        Size:{ size:'XL',size_id:234}
    }
},
 {
    product:{"final_price": 100,"customers_basket_quantity": 5,"products_id": 124, "products_name": 'silk'},
     attribute:{
        Color:{color:'blue',123,color_id:124}
    }
},
]
```

I want to change it like the format I have shown below. so I can append in formdata of API:-

```
product :[
{
"final_price": 500,
        "customers_basket_quantity": 3,
        "products_id": 123,
        "products_name": 'cotton',
        'attribute':[
            {
                'color':'red',
                'color_id':123,
            },
            {
                'size':'XL',
                'size_id':234,
            }
        ]
},
{
"final_price": 100,
        "customers_basket_quantity": 5,
        "products_id": 124,
        "products_name": 'silk',
        'attribute':[
            {
                'color':'blue',
                'color_id':124,
            }
        ]
}
]
```

how can I do that?
I tried various things but it didn't work for me!!!
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with some [destructering](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) each object into a new one.

```js
const data=[{product:{final_price:500,customers_basket_quantity:3,products_id:123,products_name:"cotton"},attribute:{Color:{color:"red",color_id:123},Size:{size:"XL",size_id:234}}},{product:{final_price:100,customers_basket_quantity:5,products_id:124,products_name:"silk"},attribute:{Color:{color:"blue",color_id:124},Size:{size:"XL",size_id:234}}}];

const result = data.map(({product, attribute, ...rest}) => {
  return {
    ...product,
    attribute: Object.values(attribute),
    ...rest
  };
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; };
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values#:%7E:text=enumerable%20property%20values.-,Description,values%20of%20the%20object%20manually.) to get an array of values of the object and use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate and create a new array with it.

```
Object.values(JSON).map(data => ({
    ...data.product,
    attribute: Object.values(data.attribute)
}));
```